# .Net code slower on AMD Opteron CPU than Intel Xeon

Tags: .net, cpu, x86-64, amd-processor

I have encountered a situation where a simple .net fibonnacci code is slower on a particular set of servers and the only thing that is obviously different is the CPU:

- AMD Opteron Processor 6276 - 11 secs
- Intel Xeon CPU E7 - 4850 - 7 secs

Code is compiled for x86 and using .NET Framework 4.0.

- Clock speeds between both is similar and in fact PassMark benchmark gives higher scores for AMD.
- Have tried this on other AMD servers in the farm and the times are slower.
- Even my local I7 machines runs the code faster.

Fibonnacci code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int ITERATIONS = 10000;
        const int FIBONACCI = 100000;

        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();


        DoFibonnacci(ITERATIONS, FIBONACCI);

        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Total fibonacci time: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DoFibonnacci(int ITERATIONS, int FIBONACCI)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
        {
            Fibonacci(FIBONACCI);
        }
    }

    private static int Fibonacci(int x)
    {
        var previousValue = -1;
        var currentResult = 1;

        for (var i = 0; i <= x; ++i)
        {
            var sum = currentResult + previousValue;
            previousValue = currentResult;
            currentResult = sum;
        }

        return currentResult;
    }

}
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Did you look at the multi-core PassMark score? It's often deceptively high for new-ish AMDs, with their high core count but relatively weak cores.

Comment: If I set the CPU affinity to a single CPU for the process then I do indeed get 7 seconds which is interesting.

Comment: You can buy *four* of these Opteron processors for the price of *one* of that Xeon processor.  You are ahead, it isn't four times slower.  The Bulldozer micro-architecture didn't impress anybody when it was released in 2011, you sound similarly underwhelmed.  Never trust a bench-mark that you haven't falsified yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant - Starting to feel the same as you

Comment: Pretty much it. AMD majorly f**** up with bulldozer - never got the speed they wanted. AMD is known today for cheap but slow processors. THeir hope? 2016.... the new architecture. So, yes, AMD is slow. Known fact. Nothing .NET related here.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal - different CPU models can have different architectures and have different performance for a specific task at the same frequency. The benchmark you're referring to is comprised of set of different computation tasks and is likely irrelevant to your specific task.

Comment: That's what I thought initially but then the specific code I'm running is also 3-4 secs slower which seems to be the bottleneck and the results seem relative to the simple fibonnacci test above.

Comment: @Rubans: That just means your specific code is affected by the architecture difference the same way as your test code.

Comment: That's what I was getting which is interesting.